# How to log output of webpack build and watch when running compiler through nodejs

Tags: node.js, webpack

We are in a specific case where we can't use webpack-dev-server because webpack only handles compilation of a sub-section of our codebase. But we still want to enable live reloading so we're rolling our own socket.io based reloading system which hooks into a nodejs instance of webpack compiler instead of CLI.

The problem is when running webpack with the cli, webpack --watch, you get a nice output to stdout. We can't figure out how to get this output when calling webpack directly in nodejs via compiler.run()

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Upon further thought the output I am looking for is not incremental but rather a large dump at the end of compilation.

Which is easily achievable with

```js
compiler.run((err,stats)=>{

  if(err) return console.error(err)

  console.log(
    stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      modules: true,
      children: true,
      chunks: true,
      chunkModules: true
    }) + '\n'
  )

  console.log("Compiled!")

})
```

Although I did find a way to log incrementally using the ProgressPlugin, although it doesn't seem to have a built-in colouring system. And it doesn't seem to output any chunk information.